# WSO2 ESB Class Mediation to continue in case of Exception

Tags: java, soap, wso2-esb

I have the following class mediator.

```
public class TestCustomMediator extends AbstractMediator {

    @Override
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {

    String processedMobile = mc
                .getEnvelope()
                .getBody()
                .getFirstElement()
                .getFirstChildWithName(
                        new QName("http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice", "mobile_no"))
                .getText();

        processedMobile = "000" + processedMobile;

        System.out.println("processedMobile===" + processedMobile);

        mc.getEnvelope()
                .getBody()
                .getFirstElement()
                .getFirstChildWithName(
                        new QName("http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice", "mobile_no"))
                .setText(processedMobile);

        return true;
    }
}
```

If the SOAP message is as expected, the mediation happens without any issue.

In case of an exception, say if the there is no child node with  name "mobile_no" then the mediation doesn't happen. It stops at that point. Doesn't continue to the next mediator.

Please let me know what should be done, even if the node traversing fails, the mediation to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no child node with name `mobile_no` you get a `NullPointerException` and custom mediator fails. So I added a null pointer check.

```
public class TestCustomMediator extends AbstractMediator {

    @Override
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {

        OMElement mobileElement = mc
            .getEnvelope()
            .getBody()
            .getFirstElement()
            .getFirstChildWithName(
                new QName("http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice", "mobile_no"))

        if (mobileElement != null) {
            String mobileNumber = mobileElement.getText();
            mobileNumber = "000" + mobileNumber;
            System.out.println("mobileNumber===" + mobileNumber);
            mc.getEnvelope()
                .getBody()
                .getFirstElement()
                .getFirstChildWithName(
                    new QName("http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice", "mobile_no"))
                .setText(mobileNumber);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood, can check for the OMElement nullity and continue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Yasothar great if you need further help regarding this issue please let me know.